# Passing a variable through URL using a list in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, web-scraping

I am very new to Python and having a bit of trouble passing a variable through a URL using a list from Excel and then creating a loop.

I tested my first code and used a variable and it worked. I also tested my second code and was able to see my list of UPC numbers.

I am using this code to scrape product data using a UPC number

```
import requests
import json

id = 5010993689026

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  
}
resp = requests.get(f'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc={id}', headers=headers)
data = json.loads(resp.text)
for item in data['items']:
  print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}-{}".format(item['ean'], item['title'], item['brand'], item['lowest_recorded_price'], item['highest_recorded_price']))
  for offer in item['offers']:
    print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(offer['domain'], offer['title'], offer['price']))
```

I also have a code that houses several UPC numbers:

```
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook


xl = pd.ExcelFile("C:/Users/Cody Sparrow/Desktop/Collection.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
for i in df.index:
    print(df['Barcode'])
```

What do I need to do to join these and create a loop? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn about functions and passing information to them. And iterating on lists.
I took your upper code and made a function out of it.

Then once your bring in the Excel data, you can make a list of the barcodes and iterate on them. Each iteration uses the main function to do what you you wanted.

```py
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook


import requests
import json

import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import time

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  
}

def get_info_with_barcode(barcode_id):
    '''
    Takes: Takes a barcode as input.
    Uses the barcode to look up information.

    Returns: nothing; however does print out details related to what is learned
    about that barcode.
    '''
    resp = requests.get(
        f'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc={barcode_id}',
        headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(resp.text)
    for item in data['items']:
      print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}-{}".format(item['ean'], item['title'], item['brand'], item['lowest_recorded_price'], item['highest_recorded_price']))
      for offer in item['offers']:
        print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(offer['domain'], offer['title'], offer['price']))



xl = pd.ExcelFile("C:/Users/Cody Sparrow/Desktop/Collection.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
barcode_list = df['Barcode'].tolist()


#barcode_list = ["5010993689026","5010993689026"] #for testing since file not supplied with barcodes. Comment out to actually run!!!

for each_barcode in barcode_list:
    get_info_with_barcode(each_barcode)
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    time.sleep(3) # to avoid slamming the site and getting blocked. Adjust or remove as needed
```

Notebook with that code in the test configuration to assign `barcode_list` (because Excel file not provided) is [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/b037c962e5e3e7ad4da45ef40deb0dc7).
[Click here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/fomightez/69b1c292c5593c216e805bc80e524a2e/cddc12b7dc8c143273b9922a91b6b51577a0550a?urlpath=git-pull%3Frepo%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgist.github.com%252Ffomightez%252Fb037c962e5e3e7ad4da45ef40deb0dc7%26urlpath%3Dretro%252Ftree%252Fb037c962e5e3e7ad4da45ef40deb0dc7%252Fso_answer.ipynb) to launch that notebook in an active Jupyter session served via MyBinder.org with the environment specified [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/69b1c292c5593c216e805bc80e524a2e/cddc12b7dc8c143273b9922a91b6b51577a0550a).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great!  Since it is not returning a value, but still printing out details, can it still be written to Excel?

Comment: There's several options. If you uncomment the extra print statement I added (begins `print("---`) in the main loop just to separate the individual output produced, you may be able to paste that directly into Excel. Tried that? If you are going to produce a lot and not have to do clunky copy-paste, you'll either want to either collect the information in a dictionary with the barcode_id as keys and the information as values or write out to `.tsv` file as you go along or at end. Excel can read `tsv`. If you collect  a dictionary, you can make a dataframe from it & use Pandas to save to Excel.

Comment: I ran out of room or I would have added that the writing out to a text file in `.tsv` format seems to be the direction you were heading?  If that sounds like what you want and each print statement you had in your first post is a separate row, I can easily add output to a text file (TSV format) in the notebook. Otherwise you need to provide more guidance. The storing of the information as a dictionary is more full-featured but might be more than you need at this time. Or might be something you can work towards learning about.

Comment: Wayne, thank you so much. I am currently reading through "Automate the Boring Stuff" and learning quite a bit about Python. This project is just a personal project for fun. I collect Star Wars, Ghostbusters, and other memorabilia. I am trying to create a database to house my collection. Ideally, I would add a UPC to the Excel sheet, Python pulls the data and stores it back into my spreadsheet. There are a few apps that do something similar, but I like the idea of having something custom that can be built to my specs. Hope you had a great Thanksgiving! Thanks, again!

Comment: Just so you know, if you invest some more effort by using Pandas and not just saving to Tab-separated values, you benefit be being able to automate the addition of stylings, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel . That demo doesn't really illustrate the possibilities well but look at more examples above that, and be sure to note only one of the methods translates to Excel, see the last one in [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Methods-to-Add-Styles).